# Javascript overlay: why is the overlay not showing when image is clicked?

Tags: javascript

Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/frempong69/8z2y0gw1

```
    //create di and assign id of overlay
    var over = document.createElement("div");
    over.setAttribute("id", "overlay");

    //create image
    var image = document.createElement("img");

    //create body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    //append image to over

    over.appendChild(image);

    //append over to body
    body.appendChild(over);


    //when clicked on a, prevent default
    //get a elements
    var gallery = document.getElementById("imageGallery");

    //a elements
    var imgs = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");
    //looping through all images
    var len = imgs.length;

    for( i = 0; i < len; i++){
    //add event of click to imgs
    var singleimg = imgs[i];
    singleimg.addEventListener("click", clicca, false);
      }

    function clicca(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //get href of a pressed
    var href = this.getAttribute("href");
    //set attribute of image to href
    image.setAttribute("src", href);
    image.setAttribute("width", "400px");
    image.setAttribute("height", "300px");
    //show over (by adding class)
    console.log(image);
   over.classList.add("open");
   //append over to body
   body.appendChild(over);

 }
```

Comment: Side notes: `over.setAttribute("id", "overlay");` can be more concisely written `over.id = "overlay";` Similarly, `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` => `document.body`.

Comment: Re your question: I don't see anything that would make that div be anywhere but at the bottom of the document. Remember that the full content of your question must be **in your question**, not just linked. Put your HTML and CSS **in** the question if you want people to help. You can even make a complete **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: Pls upvote and mark as correct if helped you.

Comment: Please take a look here:  https://jsfiddle.net/yaw69/f9jmo33z/  to understand what I am referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several problems:

1 - You have to add function `clicca` before it's assignment in click event for the `image tags`:

2 - You need to change the css to fit the div: like `#overlay.open`

you need to make this change to `#overlay.open` cos your `#overlay` **already** has all the attribute that you want to change when use `.open`.

**see:**

```
#overlay {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  transform: translateX(9999px); 
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-align:center;
}

.open{
    transform: translateX(0px);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
```

In css the preference of the style follows :

> [id>class>tags](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/css-101-handling-multiple-rules-for-the-same-element/)

In this case when you add class `.open` none of the style will change in the `div`. because all `#overlay` has all the preferences over `.open`.

**You have 2 options:**

force the class `.open` to add the style using **`!important`** like:

```
.open{
    transform: translateX(0px)!important;
    top: 0!important;
    left: 0!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    width: 100%!important;

}
```

**OR**

making you style more more **preferable** then `#overlay`. 
adding `#overlay.open`, now the css engine will process the `#overlay.open` over `#overlay`.

check this new version: https://jsfiddle.net/8z2y0gw1/1/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Seem to be working but don't understand why I need to change the css class in #overlay.open. An explanation would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @Drew just added the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Change `.open` to `#overlay.open` in your CSS.